# Pooled logins/logouts causing overloaded server

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate, optimization, connection-pooling

I have an ASP.net web application with a large amount of user visits. I have used NHibernate as my ORM (with `SQL Server 2005 SP3`), and it has worked fine. However, it has been about two months now that my dedicated server has reached 100% CPU usage. I found that 90% of this usage is from SQLServr.exe, so I used the NHibernate profiler to find the problem.

I see this in my profiler trace result:

```
Audit Login
(Some Query Execution)
Audit Logout
```

When I look at the "EventSubClass" column, and all login(s) and logout(s) were pooled!

What is the problem with these multiple logins and logouts?

Comment: did you ever find a cause for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem completely. SQL Server will pool connections by default. This is a performance enhancement. When NH connects it does so through the standard mechanisms and so you are seeing the audit of the login and logout events. Am I misunderstanding the problem?